# Como fazer uma busca em arquivo txt?

Tags: c, c++

Como faço uma busca em um arquivo `.txt` que contenha por exemplo uma lista de nomes numerados, tipo:

```
1 - João
2 - Maria
...
```

Eu informaria o número desejado e o retorno seria o nome, ou diria que nada foi encontrado. Pode ser em C, ou C++.

Comment: Se a ideia é fazer múltiplas pesquisas seria aconselhavel tratar o ficheiro uma única vez no principio do programa e guardar os dados em memória até o programa terminar.

Comment: Os numeros estão ordenados? Correspondem ao numero da linha?

Comment: Sim, quero que procure pelo numero que o usuário digitar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em C++ podes fazer da seguinte forma:

```
string getNome(string numero) {

    ifstream ifs( "ficheiro.txt" );
    string linha;
    string resultado = "Nada foi encontrado";

    while( getline( ifs, linha) ) {
        if (linha.find(numero, 0) != string::npos) {
           //cout << "encontrou: " << numero << " linha: " << linha << endl;
           resultado = linha.substr(linha.find('-', 0) + 2, linha.length() );
        }
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

No seguimento do comentário do @pmg, e se a intenção é fazer múltiplas pesquisas podes tentar algo do género:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<map>

class MapaNomes{
public:
    MapaNomes(string nomeFicheiro) {
       ifstream ifs(nomeFicheiro);
       string linha;
       string numero;

       while(getline(ifs, linha)) {
          numero = linha.substr(0, linha.find('-', 0), -1);
          nome = linha.substr(linha.find('-', 0) + 2, linha.length());

          nomes.insert(pair<int, string>(stoi(numero), name));
      }
    }

    string getNome(int numero) {
        map<int, string>::iterator it = nomes.find(numero);
        return (it != nomes.end()) ? it->second : "Nada foi encontrado";
    }
private:
    map<int, string> nomes;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MapaNomes mNomes("lista_nomes.txt");

    cout << "Procurar 1, Resultado: " << mNomes.getNome(1) << endl;
    cout << "Procurar 2, Resultado: " << mNomes.getNome(2) << endl;
    cout << "Procurar 3, Resultado: " << mNomes.getNome(3) << endl;
    cout << "Procurar 4, Resultado: " << mNomes.getNome(4) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Assume-se que o teu ficheiro está formatado de forma consistente. Caso não seja esse o caso, tens que ajustar e melhorar a forma como o número e o nome correspondente estão a ser capturados.

Mas posso perguntar o porquê de fazer isto em C ou C++? É um exercicio apenas?

Comment: Sim é um exercício para aplicar determinados métodos de busca e verificar o desempenho de cada. Irei testar seu código obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Para procurar o elemento número 11 usas awk!:

```
awk '$1==11{print $3}' ficheiro.txt
```

se tiveres mesmo que usar C

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char s[100]; int n;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  sprintf(s,"awk '$1==%d {print $3}' ficheiro.txt", n);
  system(s);
}
```

Comment: É meio perigoso usar sprintf para montar scripts como  você está fazendo. Nesse caso específico em que a entrada do usuário é um número não tem problema mas em geral é fácil esquecer de escapar alguma coisa e acabar com uma vulnerabilidade de injeção de código.

Comment: @hugomg, Concordo, (neste caso a questão não é problemática mas concordo)